# Qual seria a forma de validar os dígitos verificadores de CPF em um DB usando apenas um SELECT?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, algoritmo, sql-select, brasil

Achar informações de como calcular os dígitos verificadores do CPF não é nada difícil. Qualquer busca no Google dá inúmeros resultados. A maioria é confiável e tem até uma fonte bastante respeitada que é a entrada sobre **[CPF na Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPF)** (onde infelizmente alguns códigos previamente existentes foram removidos). Alguns dos algoritmos apresentados ali estão em melhor forma que outros.

Lá tem até como fazer isso em PL/SQL. Mas a dúvida seria como fazer o cálculo dos dígitos e obter se este cálculo é válido ou inválido usando apenas o comando `SELECT` do SQL, preferencialmente com sintaxe ANSI ou tão próxima quanto possível. Mas o mais importante é o algoritmo mesmo, mais do que um aspecto técnico específico.

O algoritmo nesta forma é útil quando não se tem acesso a um sistema de banco de dados com *Stored Procedures* ou privilégios para criar uma SP em uma base de dados.

Se ajudar, inicialmente o formato do dado não contém sinais separadores.

Este é um cenário onde não se sabe se os dados contidos na base de dados são confiáveis ou não. Montar um `SELECT` em um algoritmo, que geralmente é feito utilizando códigos mais complexos, como demonstrado na Wikipedia, não é algo tão trivial.

Alternativas que ajudem resolver o problema da forma **correta** serão apreciadas. Obviamente não pode haver falsos positivos ou negativos, o que destruiria o propósito.

Desconheço local onde há documentação oficial sobre o assunto. Já procurei bastante e não achei, pelo menos nos lugares óbvios. É incrível como falta fonte oficial em todos os locais onde se ensina fazer o cálculo. Mas ele é algo bem conhecido no Brasil.

Não importa a [verificação da situação cadastral na Receita Federal](http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/aplicacoes/atcta/cpf/consultapublica.asp), somente se os dígitos estão corretos.

Comment: Esta pergunta já foi feita antes aqui e foi removida devido a problemas na sua concepção, agressividade gerada nos comentários e principalmente por ter respostas incorretas. Atendendo ao pedido do Zuul em http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1143/101 (leia toda a discussão, é útil para o aprendizado de toda comunidade) aqui vai uma oportunidade da pergunta ter uma resposta correta, já que ela é muito útil ao site, seja para dar informações iniciais sobre o cálculo ou para conhecer um algoritmo otimizado para "caber" em um SELECT. Espero ter ajudado no pouco tempo que tenho disponível.

Comment: @bigown excelente ter recuperado a pergunta.

Comment: muito bom ter a pergunta ajudando aqui de novo hahaha

Comment: O algorítimo por trás da criação de número de cpf pode ser entendido melhor aqui neste link http://www.geradorcpf.com/algoritmo_do_cpf.htm

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## Query para cálculo e validação do dígito do CPF

Utilizei o MySQL como base, mas é relativamente simples adaptar para outros "dialetos".

**Versão para bases sem formatação, no padrão 00000000000**

```
SELECT id, nome, cpf, CONCAT( @dig1:=(
      SUBSTR(cpf,1,1)   + SUBSTR(cpf,2,1)*2 + SUBSTR(cpf,3,1)*3+
      SUBSTR(cpf,4,1)*4 + SUBSTR(cpf,5,1)*5 + SUBSTR(cpf,6,1)*6+
      SUBSTR(cpf,7,1)*7 + SUBSTR(cpf,8,1)*8 + SUBSTR(cpf,9,1)*9 ) % 11 % 10
   ,(
      SUBSTR(cpf,2,1)   + SUBSTR(cpf,3,1)*2 + SUBSTR(cpf,4,1)*3 + 
      SUBSTR(cpf,5,1)*4 + SUBSTR(cpf,6,1)*5 + SUBSTR(cpf,7,1)*6 + 
      SUBSTR(cpf,8,1)*7 + SUBSTR(cpf,9,1)*8 + @dig1          *9 ) % 11 % 10
   ) AS digito FROM cadastro;
```

**Versão para o CPF formatado, no padrão 000.000.000-00**

Esta query já considera um CPF armazenado como grupos de 3 dígitos separados por
ponto e traço da maneira tradicional (ou qualquer outro separador, desde que seja um só entre cada grupo).
Basicamente foram mudados os valores de ínício dos `SUBSTR`.

```
SELECT id, nome, cpf, CONCAT( @dig1:=(
      SUBSTR(cpf, 1,1)   + SUBSTR(cpf, 2,1)*2 + SUBSTR(cpf, 3,1)*3 +
      SUBSTR(cpf, 5,1)*4 + SUBSTR(cpf, 6,1)*5 + SUBSTR(cpf, 7,1)*6 +
      SUBSTR(cpf, 9,1)*7 + SUBSTR(cpf,10,1)*8 + SUBSTR(cpf,11,1)*9 ) % 11 % 10
   ,(
      SUBSTR(cpf, 2,1)   + SUBSTR(cpf, 3,1)*2 + SUBSTR(cpf, 5,1)*3 +
      SUBSTR(cpf, 6,1)*4 + SUBSTR(cpf, 7,1)*5 + SUBSTR(cpf, 9,1)*6 +
      SUBSTR(cpf,10,1)*7 + SUBSTR(cpf,11,1)*8 + @dig1           *9 ) % 11 % 10
   ) AS digito FROM cadastro;
```

> [Clique aqui para ver um teste funcional no **SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20a06/3/0).
>   <sub>(os números foram gerados por uma ferramenta online de terceiros, e em dois deles coloquei erros propositalmente)</sub>

Caso a idéia seja apenas identificar os CPFs válidos ou não, basta simplesmente mover a fórmula para a clausula `WHERE`:

```
-- Retorna os registros com CPF inválido:
SELECT id, nome, cpf FROM cadastro WHERE SUBSTR(cpf,13,2) != CONCAT( @dig1:=(
   ... o resto permanece igual ...
   );
```

Para o formato 00000000000, basta ajustar o `IF( SUBSTR(cpf,13,2)...` para `IF( SUBSTR(cpf,10,2)...`, e copiar a parte certa dos blocos acima.

Adicionalmente, após a verificação dos dígitos, pode-se localizar os CPFs inválidos com digito válido, de 000.000.000-00 a 999.999.999-99. Mas isso realmente merece uma query separada.

Comment: Muito bom! Só faltava mesmo o tal link para documentação sobre esse famoso CPF :) +1

Comment: @Zuul o bigown pos na pergunta

Comment: @Zuul a propósito, eu andei acertando um dos códigos da WP, mas um sujeito reverteu (era uma multiplicação por 11 pra fazer módulo 11 em seguida, ou seja, sem sentido). Depois vou lá conferir como está.

Comment: Vi esse link na pergunta, esperava algo mais detalhado... mas se calhar nem há! :/ De qualquer forma continua ai o bom trabalho ;)

Comment: @Zuul entendo como é; é que no Brasil esse número é mais importante até do que o documento de identidade, pra muitas coisas. É quase como o  "seguro social" dos EUA, mas pra quem é de fora não deve fazer o mínimo sentido mesmo.

Comment: @Zuul Mas como você já deve ter se acostumando, nós costumamos dizer redundantemente que as coisas aqui no Brasil viram "Brasil" :) Ou seja, um dos cálculos mais importantes que se pode fazer oficialmente no país não tem documentação facilmente acessível. Quem puder indicar algo oficial, #ficaAdica :)

Comment: @Zuul aqui no Brasil CPF é o **C** adastro **P** essoa **F** ísica. Aqui: http://i.imgur.com/A1hAgpS.jpg

Answer (score 4):

Eu utilizo o script abaixo em SQLServer para validação de um CPF.
Pode-se criar uma função e chama-la por select

```
CREATE FUNCTION CPF_VALIDO(@CPF VARCHAR(11))
RETURNS CHAR(1)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @INDICE INT,
               @SOMA INT,
               @DIG1 INT,
               @DIG2 INT,
               @CPF_TEMP VARCHAR(11),
               @DIGITOS_IGUAIS CHAR(1),
               @RESULTADO CHAR(1)

   SET @RESULTADO = 'N'

   /*
         Verificando se os digitos são iguais
         A Principio CPF com todos o números iguais são Inválidos
         apesar de validar o Calculo do digito verificado
         EX: O CPF 00000000000 é inválido, mas pelo calculo
         Validaria
   */

   SET @CPF_TEMP = SUBSTRING(@CPF,1,1)

   SET @INDICE = 1
   SET @DIGITOS_IGUAIS = 'S'

   WHILE (@INDICE <= 11)
   BEGIN
      IF SUBSTRING(@CPF,@INDICE,1) <> @CPF_TEMP
         SET @DIGITOS_IGUAIS = 'N'
      SET @INDICE = @INDICE + 1
   END;

   --Caso os digitos não sejão todos iguais Começo o calculo do digitos
   IF @DIGITOS_IGUAIS = 'N' 
   BEGIN
      --Cálculo do 1º dígito
      SET @SOMA = 0
      SET @INDICE = 1
      WHILE (@INDICE <= 9)
      BEGIN
         SET @Soma = @Soma + CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(@CPF,@INDICE,1)) * (11 - @INDICE);
         SET @INDICE = @INDICE + 1
      END

      SET @DIG1 = 11 - (@SOMA % 11)

      IF @DIG1 > 9
         SET @DIG1 = 0;

      -- Cálculo do 2º dígito }
      SET @SOMA = 0
      SET @INDICE = 1
      WHILE (@INDICE <= 10)
      BEGIN
         SET @Soma = @Soma + CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(@CPF,@INDICE,1)) * (12 - @INDICE);
         SET @INDICE = @INDICE + 1
      END

      SET @DIG2 = 11 - (@SOMA % 11)

      IF @DIG2 > 9
         SET @DIG2 = 0;

      -- Validando
      IF (@DIG1 = SUBSTRING(@CPF,LEN(@CPF)-1,1)) AND (@DIG2 = SUBSTRING(@CPF,LEN(@CPF),1))
         SET @RESULTADO = 'S'
      ELSE
         SET @RESULTADO = 'N'
   END
   RETURN @RESULTADO
END
```