# Validar CPF usando WPF

Tags: c#

Como posso verificar se um número de CPF é valido usando o WPF em C#?

É preciso criar alguma classe?

Comment: O que você já tentou? Fica muito vago a pergunta assim.

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11470/101

Answer (score 3):

> Como posso verificar se um número de CPF é valido usando o WPF em C#? [...]

Primeiramente, usar ou não WPF não faz diferença nenhuma. A linguagem é C# e é isso que importa. Para saber se um CPF é válido, existe um algoritmo que pode ser facilmente encontrado na internet.

Perceba que o algoritmo apenas pode verificar se um CPF é **válido** segundo a regras estabelecidas pelo país e não se ele é um CPF ativo ou não.

> [...] É preciso criar alguma classe?

Depende da sua organização, tanto faz. Eu tenho uma classe **`Valida`** que uso para fazer algumas validações num dos meus projetos.

Abaixo o código que uso para validar CPF's, o algoritmo foi retirado [daqui](http://www.geradorcpf.com/algoritmo_do_cpf.htm).
Talvez sejam necessárias algumas modificações, mas a base é essa e ele está completamente funcional dessa maneira.

<sub>Veja que o algoritmo pede um inteiro como parâmetro, se você salva o CPF com pontos e traço, é necessário removê-los e converter para inteiro antes de tentar validar (ou adaptar a função para receber no formato que você salva).</sub>

```
using static System.Convert;

public static class Valida
{
    public static bool Cpf(int cpf)
    {
        string strCpf = cpf.ToString().PadLeft(11, '0');

        if (strCpf.All(x => x == strCpf[0]))
            return false;

        var listCpf = strCpf.Select(num => ToInt32(num.ToString())).ToList();

        if (listCpf[9] != Mod11Cpf(listCpf, 10))
            return false;

        if (listCpf[10] != Mod11Cpf(listCpf, 11))
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    internal static int Mod11Cpf(List<int> elementos, int @base)
    {
        int soma = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < (@base - 1); i++)
            soma += (@base - i) * elementos[i];

        int dv1, resto = soma % 11;

        if (resto < 2)
            dv1 = 0;
        else
            dv1 = 11 - resto;

        return dv1;
    }
}
```